# JMeter uses 3 connections in distributed setup? What data is sent?

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

JMeter can be used to generate distributed tests using master-slave pattern.
According to this page [Performance Testing in the Cloud with JMeter & AWS](https://www.artofsoftwaredevelopment.com/performance/performance-testing-in-the-cloud-with-jmeter-aws), a connection between a master and a slave uses 3 connections: two for RMI(remote method invocation) and one is reserved for JMeter.

[image]

Question: Do you know what data is sent over those connections? I want to understand the scope better of those 3 connections.

Thank you guys